# What is the correct way to use position:fixed with no overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have my *topbar* which is just a `div` with `position:fixed`. What is the correct way to not overlap the content below?

Sure, I can wrap the content in a `div` and give it a `margin-top` of the same height as the *topbar*.

But what if I dynamically load content on the *topbar* which changes its height? I can dynamically change the `margin-top` of the content `div` as well, but is it the more elegant way to do this?

Comment: not really other than setting fixed height and constraining overflow

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this is to add `margin` or `padding` to the page content below the header. When you use `position:fixed`, it is taken out of the page's layout calculation and the page's content needs to be adjusted to accomodate it.

You can also use Javascript to dynamically change the `margin` of the content based on the height of the header. Once the page loads, you can use something like jQuery's `height()` method to get the height of the header and then adjust the css for the page's content based on that result.

Comment: I generally use a CSS sibling selector to apply the style to the container, as then the container still works when the header is not present.

Something like the following:

`.header.is-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    height: 50px;
}

.header.is-fixed + .container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}`

Comment: That seems like a good solution if the header is removed from the page. This question deals with the header always being present, so it won't work in this situation. But save this advice when that question comes up - good stuff!